# GoogleAnalytics android getActivity().getApplication() cannot cast to AnalyticsApplication

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

this the code where I got the error

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // Obtain the shared Tracker instance.
        AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getActivity().getApplication();
        mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
}
```

this is my AnalyticsApplication class

```
package auc.games2.Analytics;
/*
 * Copyright Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */


        import android.app.Application;

        import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
        import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Logger;
        import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

        import auc.games2.R;

/**
 * This is a subclass of {@link Application} used to provide shared objects for this app, such as
 * the {@link Tracker}.
 */
public class AnalyticsApplication extends Application {
    private Tracker mTracker;

    /**
     * Gets the default {@link Tracker} for this {@link Application}.
     * @return tracker
     */
    synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
        if (mTracker == null) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
            mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
        }
        return mTracker;
    }
}
```

this is the error on logcat

> 03-09 18:46:11.070 32602-32602/auc.games2.multigame1 E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast
>   to auc.games2.Analytics.AnalyticsApplication
>                                                                              at auc.games2.UI.Fragments.inicial.onViewCreated(inicial.java:127)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:843)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
>                                                                              at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1399)
>                                                                              at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
>                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `AndroidManifest.xml` file does not contain your custom `Application` subclass, so Android is using the default one (`android.app.Application`).

Add an `android:name="auc.games2.Analytics.AnalyticsApplication"` attribute to your `<application>` element.