# Android - App crashing with "java.lang.ClassCastException"

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, classcastexception

I am using a [tutorial provided by Google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) to implement **Analytics** in my app but something I possibly did wrong that causes the app to crash with `java.lang.ClassCastException`

This is what Google provided:

```
// Obtain the shared Tracker instance.
AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
```

This is the changes I made because I am using a **Fragment**

```
// This is where I get the error
AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getContext().getApplicationContext();
mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
```

**UPDATE :** The error happens at this line:

```
AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getContext().getApplicationContext();
```

This is my LogCat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.incorp.labs.appname, PID: 14095
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.incorp.labs.appname.Helper.AnalyticsTracker
  at com.incorp.labs.appname.OneFragment.onCreateView(OneFragment.java:126)
```

**UPDATE 2 :** This is the Manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.incorp.labs.appname">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/newlogops"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".OneFragment"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TwoFragment"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Feedback"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FourFragment"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashTimer"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

    <service android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>                     
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
             
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity android:name=".AboutActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: 1)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312255/error-on-my-fragment-android-app-application-cannot-be-cast-to

2)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24950341/android-google-analytics-integration-error

Comment: According to documentation this is only thrown when a code has attempted to cast an Object to a subclass of which is not an instance. AnalyticsApplication and AnalyticsTracker

Comment: @Lokesh I changed the class name, but that shouldn't be a problem right ?

Comment: I think that you didn't declare your custom application in your manifest. SHow the manifest.

Comment: @VladMatvienko yes correct I don't think I did, how to do so please ?

Comment: `SHow the manifest.`

Comment: @VladMatvienko done! check the updates question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to implementing the `extends Application` class, you need to tell Android system which class to use as an Application class. To do so, set the name of your application class in manifest:

```
<application
        android:name="your.package.AnalyticsApplication"
```

Comment: this seems to be the solution but I get "Unresolved class" when I added `android:name="..."` my packaage looks like this: `com.incorp.labs.appname`

Comment: @ThorvaldÓlavsenV. show how exactly have you added.

Comment: like this: `android:name="com.incorp.labs.appname.AnalyticsApplication"`

Comment: @ThorvaldÓlavsenV., are you sure that `AnalyticsApplication` is in package  `com.incorp.labs.appname`?

Comment: it is fixed now! the class was inside a subfolder that I overlooked

Answer (score 4):

Just change this :-

```
AnalyticsTracker application = (AnalyticsTracker) getContext().getApplicationContext();
```

to this :-

```
AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getContext().getApplicationContext();
```

It's one of those obvious errors that happen with the best of us!

Comment: I changed the class name on purpose, does it make any difference ?

Comment: It's not about the class name. It's the fact that you're trying to cast an `AnalyticsApplication` object to an `AnalyticsTracker` object. Thus, the `ClassCastException` occurs. It's been done correctly in the Google code that you posted.

Comment: no I made all the changes and I still have the same error, check the updated answer where I specify the line

Comment: I don't think you should be getting an error now. Could you clean and rebuild and run again?

Comment: unfortunately it didn't

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild and reinstall the application? Your LogCat specifically points to the error that I have mentioned.

Comment: yes I did everything you told me and followed all your steps

Comment: Well, that's odd. Could you post your entire updated Fragment code and the  latest LogCat error?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to use a Context object (getApplicationContext()) as an application object.

Try this: **EDIT**

```
AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getActivity().getApplication();
```

From your fragment you can call the activity that contains the fragment. When you get the activity, you can use the getApplication() function as in the example.

I hope it helps.

**EDIT 2**

As seen in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35905601/4336354 from CommonsWare user.

> Your AndroidManifest.xml file does not contain your custom Application
>   subclass, so Android is using the default one
>   (android.app.Application).
>
> Add an android:name="auc.games2.Analytics.AnalyticsApplication"
>   attribute to your  element.

Comment: Sorry, i also wrote the line wrong. It must be an AnalyticsApplication class instead of an AnalyticsTracker.

Comment: That's not the problem, I fixed it and still nothing

Comment: In which method did you write the line, in onCreate()? It will not work until the fragment is attached to the activity, so you should overwrite the onAttached() or onResume() methods.

Comment: Also check this answer, it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35905601/4336354